# Kalman Filtering, Smoothing and Parameter Estimation for State Space Models in R and C#

Tags: r, time-series, optimization, smoothing, kalman-filter

I am in the process of writing an open source State Space Analysis suite in C# (for fun). I have implemented a number of different Kalman-Based Filters (Kalman Filter, Information Filter and the Square Root Filter) and the State and Disturbance Smoothers that work with these implementations. My tests on these filters (using the Nile data from *Durban and Koopman's (DK)* book *"Time Series Analysis by State Space Methods"* and other more complex data) show that the filters and smoothers work and they produce very similar results (as you would expect for a local univariate model). The smoothed output for the basic Kalman Filter for the Nile data looks like (because everyone likes a graphic or two :])

[image: Smoothed Nile Data]

The dotted line is the 90% confidence interval.

Now, my problem; I am now attempting to write the first part of the parameter estimation code and for the parameter estimation of the covariances $\mathbf{H}_{1}$ and $\mathbf{Q}_{1}$ in the linear Gaussian State Space model

$$y_t = \mathbf{Z}_{t}\alpha_{t} + \epsilon_{t},$$
$$\alpha_{t + 1} = \mathbf{T}_{t}\alpha_{t} + \mathbf{R}_{t}\eta_{t},$$

where $y_{t}$ is our observation vector, $\alpha_{t}$ our state vector at time step $t$ and

$$\epsilon_{t} \sim NID(0, \mathbf{H}_{t}),$$
$$\eta_{t} \sim NID(0, \mathbf{Q}_{t}),$$
$$\alpha_{1} \sim NID(a_{1}, \mathbf{P}_{1}).$$

where $t = 1,\ldots, n$.

We have an implementation of the Expectation Maximisation (EM) algorithm and this is estimating $\mathbf{H} = 19550.37$ and $\mathbf{Q} = 7411.44$ with the loglikelihood converging in 32 iterations to -683.1 with a convergence tolerence of $10^-6$.

The DK book quotes $\mathbf{H} = 15099$ and $\mathbf{Q} = 1469.1$ and from [Tusell's paper](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v39/i02/paper) and [this walkthrough using R](http://www.et.bs.ehu.es/~etptupaf/N4.html) he matches this prediction getting $\mathbf{H} = 15102$ and $\mathbf{Q} = 1468$. I have debugged my code and it really seems like my implementation of the EM algorithm is correct. So get to the bottom of what is going on I want to run the same data set using R and KFAS...

Using R and the R Package [KFAS](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/KFAS/index.html), I have attempted to reproduce these estimates for $\mathbf{H}$ and $\mathbf{Q}$, but my R knowledge is weak. My current R script is as follows

```
install.packages('KFAS')
require(KFAS)

# Example of local level model for Nile series
modelNile<-SSModel(Nile~SSMtrend(1,Q=list(matrix(NA))),H=matrix(NA))
modelNile
modelNile<-fitSSM(inits=c(log(var(Nile)),log(var(Nile))),model=modelNile,
method='BFGS',control=list(REPORT=1,trace=1))$model

# Can use different optimisation: 
# should be one of “Nelder-Mead”, “BFGS”, “CG”, “L-BFGS-B”, “SANN”, “Brent”
modelNile<-SSModel(Nile~SSMtrend(1,Q=list(matrix(NA))),H=matrix(NA))
modelNile
modelNile<-fitSSM(inits=c(log(var(Nile)),log(var(Nile))),model=modelNile,
method='L-BFGS-B',control=list(REPORT=1,trace=1))$model

# Filtering and state smoothing
out<-KFS(modelNile,filtering='state',smoothing='state')
out
```

*How can I extend this R script using KFAS in order to estimate the parameters $\mathbf{H}$ and $\mathbf{Q}$?* and *Should each method of parameter estimation be hitting the same values for $\mathbf{H}$ and $\mathbf{Q}$?*

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not sure why KFS does not return `V_eta` or `V_eps`, but why not use `modelNile$H` and `modelNile$Q`? They are also kept in the return object from KFS, `out$model$H` and `out$model$Q`. You will find what the objects contains by using the `names()` function as in `names(modelNile)` or `names(out$model)`.

Answer (score 2):

Afer perusing the documentation for KFAS, it seems to me that KFS() will return
what you want in components `V_eta` and `V_eps` of the object you name `out`. (This is the case because you are dealing with a univariate time series, so 
the only diagonal term of `V_eps` is the variance you want.)

You should expect about the same values from your code and any of the packages. Discrepancies may crop up, however, on account of: i) Different initial conditions (exactly diffuse, as KFAS implements, or setting the variance of the initial state to a very large number, as you probably have done), and ii) Different criteria to stop the likelihood climbing.

Discrepancies due to different algorithms (like plain Kalman filter iteration versus square root algorithms, either covariance or information filters) may also appear with longer series and/or more complicated models, but with not the Nile data.

Please note my name's spelling: Tusell.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and sorry about the spelling of your name; I was typing very quickly. I have attempted to check the variables `out$V_eta`/`out$V_eps` but they both return `NULL`. I have also attempted this after running `modelNile<-fitSSM(...)` by using `modelNile$V_eta`/`modelNile$V_eps` but this also returns `NULL`. Again, thanks for your time...

Comment: Sorry, I did not have a chance to connect until now. Perhaps what KFS returns depend on the values you pass to filtering= and smoothing= . In the mean time, I see that @SteinarV has provided an alternative way to obtain the matrices you are after.